# Any sequence asynchronous counter

Tags: digital-logic, counter

While I can understand the logic behind synchronous counters that can implement 'any-sequence',I'm not sure how I would go about doing that with an asynchronous counter.

For example one that produces a 2->3->5->8->13->2->3->... sequence.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous means you don't have a clock signal to control the counter. There is no arbiter that will tell you when the outputs are valid. This implies that subsequent stages cannot tolerate any glitches in the counter. This in turn means you want only a single bit to change between two counts. For every current combination of output levels, you can uniquely identify the next step.

In Dutch it is called a `univariante code`, I don't know the proper English translation for it, but means that between every step only a single bit will change. Wikipedia writes: "two successive values differ in only one bit". [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) is a well known example for this. As at every moment only a single bit will change, you still get a stable counter which runs at the maximum speed of the silicon. It also means you cannot use just any arbitrary sequence you like.

If you want an arbitrary sequence, you can use output logic for your outputs but you will get glitches: illegal temporary values caused by difference in port propagation delay.

A sequence like this is easy to design using a Karnaugh map. Just make a loop without interruptions of your desired length. Here is an example 12 stage code I just made up.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the Karnaugh map. Also, I feel that [logic redundancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_redundancy) should be mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous counters differ from ripple (asynchronous) counters in that:

(1) They can be designed to produce any sequence of output signals (and so are also known as sequence generators), **whereas ripple counters can only count either up or down in binary.**

(2) The clock inputs of all stages of the counter are connected together and so receive clock pulses at exactly the same time (and that is why they are called synchronous!) Logic gates are used to generate appropriate signals at the data inputs of each stage.

(3) In asynchronous (ripple) counters, the clock signals move through the system, stage by stage, and so it takes time for the last stage to react to a pulse received at the first stage.  This causes inaccuracy when the counter is counting at high speed. There is no such problem with the synchronous counter, because all stages receive the clock signal at the same time and so react at the same time.

So the answer to your question is you don't use asynchronous counters for sequence generators.